# Google Earth 64bit won't start on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, 64-bit, google-earth

lsb-core is installed.

the problem looks like this:

```
andre@loke:~$ google-earth 
/usr/bin/google-earth: 43: /usr/bin/google-earth: ./googleearth-bin: not found
```

Comment: whats `cd /opt/google/earth/free/ ; ./googleearth-bin` get you?

Comment: It looks a lot like it didn't install correctly. How did you install it?

Comment: It installed just fine using dpkg -i

Comment: the funny ting is that /usr/bin/google-earth (shellscript) is supposed to execute the googleearth-bin   - it switches correctly to /opt/google/earth/free   then uses a unused variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH  .. and then it fails.    

The strange thing is that if I go to the "free" folder, and attempt to ./googleearth-bin    - I get  ./googleearth-bin 
"bash: ./googleearth-bin: No such file or directory"
- but I can "cat" it   , it's a binary file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem:

```
$ file googleearth-bin 
googleearth-bin: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=5e3f4d36f570e8ecae816acdb8a733830f2eff61, stripped
```

The interpreter is /lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3 but I didn't have that file

```
$ ls /lib64/
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

So I simply put there a symlink into my interpreter:

```
# ln -s /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3
```

EDIT: I just noticed that the package lsb-core is needed. Maybe the previous "solution" is not the perfect... Anyway I let it there; maybe it's useful to someone